# nice URL relative link issue

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting

I am using nice urls without rewrites (e.g. `/my/site/index.php/some/page`). I am having trouble with stylesheet links. For example, `sheet.css` is getting interpreted as `/my/site/index.php/some/sheet.css`.
How can I get it to link correctly, for any prefix (`/my/site/`) and any depth suffix (`/some/page`)?

Comment: Add more details. Are you using .htaccess for rewriting or a PHP based rewriting script?

Comment: @futuregeek As you can see from my sample, there is no apache rewrites involved. It is using a one-entry-point `index.php`.

Answer (score 1):

add a `/` in front of any resource to point them to the root directory of your site:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/sheet.css">
```

You can always setup a `CONSTANT` in your included `config` file and add the site path to it

```
define('HOST_URL', 'http://www.example.org/my/site/');
define('HOST_URL', 'http://www.example.net/my/site2/');
```

then  you can call any file and change the paths whenever you want from 1 single file.

Eg:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo HOST_URL; ?>sheet.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo HOST_URL; ?>script.js"></script>
<img src="" alt="<?php echo HOST_URL; ?>images/image.jpg" border="0" />
```

Comment: It is not in the root. It is next to my index.php file.

Comment: I need to get to `/my/site/style.css`. This takes me to `/style.css`

Comment: it's OK, if you have website: http://www.example.org/index.php, then http://www.example.org/ is the root directory

Comment: My site may be at `example.org/index.php`, or it may be at `example.org/my/site/index.php`

Comment: Its always good to refer to resources(js, css, etc) by the full path(path from the doc-root). You can use a constant like
    define("CSS_PATH", "path-to-css-dir");
and then use
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo CSS_PATH; ?>sheet.css">

Comment: @futuregeek And how would I get that path? I want this to be deployable in different scenarios, nothing hardcoded.

Comment: You cannot make something absolutely automatic. If you change your path is more likely everything will change. Especially when you mess with folders like example.org/my/site/